# Attempted import error: 'MaskedViewIOS' is not exported from 'react-native'

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-web

I want to learn react native.  I want to build a web app and an android app.  I want to be to navigate between screens of my app.  So I did this:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm install react-native-web
```

I then updated my `index.js` to look like this:

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App);
AppRegistry.runApplication('App', { rootTag: document.getElementById('root') });
```

And I updated my `App.js` to look like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({Home: {screen: function(props){return null}}});
const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
export default App;
```

When I run the `npm start` command, I get the error

```
./node_modules/react-navigation-stack/lib/module/views/Header/Header.js
Attempted import error: 'MaskedViewIOS' is not exported from 'react-native'.
```

Does anyone know how to correct this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is an issue in `react-navigation-stack` v1 with the latest version of `react-native-web` but I don't think will be fixed.

The issue is MaskedViewIOS has been moved to react-native-community [issue #132](https://github.com/react-navigation/stack/issues/132):

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-masked-view

Answer (score 1):

Update to react-navigation-stack v2